# I want to use Reader and InputStream together

Tags: java, inputstream, reader

First of all, sorry for my poor english... :)

I'm working with processing EML file with specific header...

My sample eml file is...

```
FROM IP : 1.2.3.4
TO IP : 2.3.4.5
.....
END_HEADER
from this line, standard EML format with various encoding type...
```

So, I want to read this file

At first line to END_HEADER, BufferedReader.readLine)_

And later, FileInputStream.read(byte[], 0, readLen)...

Is this possible?

my recent code is...

use my readLine() method in class...

```
public string readLine(InputSteam is) {
  int oneByte = 0;
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

  while((oneByte = is.read()) != -1)
  {
    if(oneByte != '\r' && oneByte != '\n')
      baos.write();
    else
      break;
  }

  return new String(baos.toByteArray());
}
```

I hope you understand my question... :)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You could use an instance of [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) to wrap the `InputStream` in a `Reader` which can be used by the `BufferedReader`.  From there you "should" be able to read the file with both...

Comment: I know it, but EML file's encoding type is various...(UTF-8, EUC-KR...etc...)      and source code's encoding is UTF-8...

Comment: How do you know the encoding before hand?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't know...but when I use JAVAMail, it could process automatically...

Comment: javamail implies that data is parsed within an email, and mime headers of the entity in question could specify the encoding.  If the entity itself has no method of including what its encoding use, you need something outside of the file that tells you what the encoding is or you need to use an encoding detection library.

Comment: @ewh thank you, but my question is how to use inputstream and reader together...

Comment: @MadProgrammer That will not work. The `BufferedReader` will read ahead and fill its buffer and 'steal' data from the underlying `InputStream`.

Comment: This is a rare case where using the deprecated `DataInputStream.readLine()` method is indicated, as long as the incoming character set is pretty restricted.